Is the execution of after insert trigger finished when the next entry is inserted?
I have an SQL Server database with a table with a trigger which is executed after insert. If I insert two entries directly one after another, it is important that the second entry is inserted only after the execution of the trigger has finished. Can I rely on this? Or might I get a problematic race condition at some point?
The code of the trigger looks like this:
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_MachineState_Desable_OldData_ON_Insert]
   ON [dbo].[machine_state]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
      DECLARE @RowID INT;
      DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(30);
      DECLARE @MachineState NVARCHAR(30);
      DECLARE @Devicescount INT;
      DECLARE @StartedOn DATETIME;
      DECLARE @CreateOn DATETIME;
      DECLARE @ToolName NVarchar(30);


    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
          SELECT
                   @RowID=[RowId]
                  ,@Name= [Name]
                  ,@MachineState=[MachineState]
                  ,@Devicescount=[Devicescount]
                  ,@StartedOn= [StartedOn]
                  ,@CreateOn =[ActionDate]
                  ,@ToolName=[ToolName]
        from inserted ;

    update [machine_state]
    set [IsActive]=0
    where  [Name] =@Name and  ToolName = @ToolName and  RowId <> @RowID

    update machine_state
    set IsActive =1
    where RowId=@RowID


END

As you can see, the trigger makes sure that only the last entry with the same tool name and the same name has IsActive true.

While there is no guarantee on the execution of triggers of different statements, correct locking should prevent any issues from arising.
As mentioned by others, you need to fix your giant bug where you are not handling multiple (or zero!) rows correctly.
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_MachineState_Desable_OldData_ON_Insert]
   ON [dbo].[machine_state]
   AFTER INSERT
AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;    -- early bailout

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    GROUP BY i.Name, i.ToolName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
    THROW 50001, N'Multiple duplicate active rows', 1;

UPDATE others
SET IsActive = 0
FROM dbo.machine_state others
JOIN inserted i
  ON i.Name = others.Name
 AND i.ToolName = others.ToolName
 AND i.RowId <> others.RowID;

/*
-- DO NOT DO the below. Just change your insert to do it correctly the first time.

UPDATE ms
SET IsActive = 1
FROM inserted i
JOIN dbo.machine_state ms ON ms.RowId = i.RowID;
*/

You'd need an index machine_state (Name, ToolName) INCLUDE (RowId, IsActive) for the locking to work correctly. You also need that extra check I added to ensure that someone doesn't try to add duplicate Name, ToolName rows at once, otherwise the results would be non-deterministic.

Leaving all this aside, I strongly suggest you consider using Temporal Tables, rather than trying to roll your own not-great version of the same. Temporal Tables handle archived, non-active rows automatically, then you can use a normal primary key on Name, ToolName.

oh dear
You're going to have a much bigger bugger of a problem if someone ever inserts more than a single row into that table. Your trigger will have a quite non-determinstic time of things.
But no, there is no guarantee that your trigger will have completed execution by the time another row arrives.
You may want to try your inserts under higher concurrency with a tool like SQL Query Stress.
